# access violation reading location in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, com-interop

I have a thread which reads multicast data and updates certain data structures

and another thread which is handled by chai 3d library

when I just run my library code it works fine.

when I run y thread also

I get access violation in one of the routine inside the chai3d code.

my thread code

```
    unsigned int __stdcall ThreadFunc(void* data)
{
    char *timeOld;
    int ID;
    while(1)
    {
    char *position = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(cpi->getData());
    ID = cpi->getMulticastDataID();
    char* timeNew = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(cpi->getTime());
    if(timeFirst == true)
        {
        timeOld = new char[strlen(timeNew) + 1];
        strcpy(timeOld,timeNew);
        timeFirst = false;
        }
    if((strcmp(timeNew,timeOld) != 0) && (AddItselToList == true) && ( ID != 99))
    {handlePacket(position,ID);
    strcpy(timeOld,timeNew);}
    delete[] position;
    delete[] timeNew;
    }
    delete[] timeOld;
}
```

cpi is a pointer to com c# object where getdata, gettime return strings and getmulticastid returns int.

is there something worn with my thread code?

```
_beginthreadex(NULL,0,ThreadFunc,NULL,0,NULL);
```

Comment: You have memory leaks. You should delete[] the strings returned by ConvertBSTRToString when you no longer need them.

Comment: Have you tried running the program inside a debugger? This will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what they contain. You do that first, and if you still can't figure it out then add those details to the question (especially the line in which the program crashes).

Comment: the strings are needed till the program exits! I am running it through a debugger and it gives me an address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete[] position` and `timeNew` before the closing brace of the while loop. `delete[] timeOld` before the closing brace of ThreadFunc. Also, are you sure `timeOld` is long enough to copy `timeNew` into it? This may explain your access violation.

Comment: I changed the code, I have changed it above also,   but still get access violation

Comment: @user494461 - what about the string lengths? Is it possible that timeNew is longer than timeOld? This can still be a problem in the second strcpy.